# Get JSON from a specific spreadsheet tab/page

Tags: json, tabs, spreadsheet

I'm trying to retrieve the JSON output from one of my spreadsheets. I'm looking for the second tab/page in my sheet.

```
var url2 = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID2 + "/od6/public/values?alt=json";
$.getJSON(url2, function(data) {
  //some code here
});
```

When I publish my spreadsheet to the web this piece is added to my link

```
?gid=72574160&single=true
```

I tried to put it on different places in my link but every time I get an error like this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [url] No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My question is: **how can I get the JSON from one specific tab?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution to this:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/**SPREADSHEETID**/**NUMBEROFTAB**/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData

Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CeXMU7IRDWtj57l2nM2rQHkHpkNH3jhsG_pGZ8S4CzY/edit?usp=sharing

json tab 1:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1CeXMU7IRDWtj57l2nM2rQHkHpkNH3jhsG_pGZ8S4CzY/**1**/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData

json tab 2:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1CeXMU7IRDWtj57l2nM2rQHkHpkNH3jhsG_pGZ8S4CzY/**2**/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData

Answer (score -2):

Apparently there is a nice bypass. You can access your sheet through this link.

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID/private/full
```

After that you can search for your tab name and spreadsheet URL and take that url to getJSON.